# pip install python winerror 10054

Tags: windows, installation, python, pip

Been trying to pip install selenium keep getting these same errors, but its not just selenium its any package. I believe it maybe a firewall issue because I am trying to install this on a workstation at my company. It is hard to verify because I have no experience in firewalls and all the searches on the error code are specific to certain packages or program/scripts trying to be written by coders. Need a solution or at least a reason why. I put the log and the DOS command and output below. Seems like it can't find the package went to the url where it is looking itself and found it okay. Pip can't do it itself though.

DOS:

C:\Users\kcalica\Desktop>pip install selenium Downloading/unpacking selenium Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement selenium Cleaning up... No distributions at all found for selenium Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\kcalica\pip\pip.log

C:\Users\kcalica\Desktop>

pip.log:

(only part of it)

C:\Python34\Scripts\pip run on 06/16/14 14:32:01 Downloading/unpacking selenium Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/selenium/ Could not fetch URL://pypi.python.org/simple/selenium/: connection error:... [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry forgot to answer this once I solved the question. Yes it was a block on the firewall that my company had. I just talked to IT and he opened up access for a limited time. If you have this problem talk to your IT office, or check your firewall settings.